# How can I fix keystroke delay while typing in Mail on Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, mail.app

I have Mail Version 6.0 (1485), Mountain Lion 10.8, build 12A269.

When composing messages in Mail the keystrokes are delayed. This makes typing awkward. I have not had this happen under Lion and it does not appear to be happening under any other application.

How can I fix keystroke delay while typing in Mail on Mountain Lion?

Comment: Is there anything interesting in the logs / Console.app?

Comment: Do you have any old Mail plugins installed?